# lock file on linux and if lock successful become daemon?

Tags: c, linux, unix

I want to write program that becomes daemon on demand:

```
if_there_are_no_daemon_alive_start_daemon();
pass_job_to_daemon();
```

and I stuck on implementation of `if_there_are_no_daemon_alive_start_daemon`.
At first I think of trying to lock file `/run/lock/my-unique-name.lck`,
and if succeeded then do double fork and done,
and if not then daemon is up and running and time to call `pass_job_to_daemon`.

But file lock acquired in parent process, just disappears after parent die:

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/file.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
        assert(argc > 1);
        int fd = open(argv[1], O_WRONLY | O_APPEND | O_CREAT, 0600);
        assert(fd >= 0);
        int ret = flock(fd, LOCK_EX);
        assert(ret == 0); 
        printf("get flock\n");
        pid_t pid = fork();
        assert(pid >= 0);
        if (pid == 0) {
             printf("child process\n");   
             sleep(5); //<-- no flock here according to lslocks
             printf("child done\n");                
        } else {
             printf("parent: time to exit\n");
        }
        return 0; 
}
```

So what variant of interprocessor lock can I use here,
to make check if daemon running atomic and then pass this lock to child process after double forking without problems?

Comment: `flock(2)` locks on linux are kept across forks/execs.

Comment: Standard `fcntl(2)` locks are not kept across forks.

Comment: @Shawn As you see in my example `flock(2)` are not working with fork.

Comment: Are you using WSL, by chance? There's no /proc/locks available in it (The file that this `lslocks` parses to get lock information).

Comment: @Shawn No, this is ordinary Linux on bare metal, without any kind of virtualization. Kernel 5.15.69 and glibc 2.36. And `lslocks` works, if I add sleep into parent part after fork, I can see alive lock until parent dies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lock files don't require any file locking such as `flock`. The existence of the file is used as the lock. Add `O_EXCL` to the `open` call.  If `open` succeeds, you have the lock; then to release the lock you `remove` or `unlink` the file.
You need some handling for stale lock files in the case of a crash. That's one reason they are typically created in a particular directory, because the system startup scripts know about it and delete the lock files.